# How to prevent a user from closing a python program?

Tags: debian, kiosk

I have a python program and use Debian. I want the user to automatically login into a specific account and for the python program to be automatically launched. And after this happens, the user shouldn’t be able to exit or close the program or be able to interact with anything other than it.The python program uses a text based interface

Comment: Use a resticted shell, start the program via `.profile` and trap exiting the program with a logout. The user might close the program that way, but will be logged off.

Comment: Alternatively link an ssh login to the command and trap it.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just editing /etc/passwd do the trick for you.

Last section in this file specifies the login shell. [understanding passwd file](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/)

Find Change `/bin/bash` to `/bin/python3` for that user:
[image: passwd]

So, when user logins, she/he directly enters to python and exiting would be equal to logout from machine.

Comment: He said he wanted to run a specific python script, not just the python command. In addition, depending on the the `pam` configuration of the host, he might also need to add the program to `/etc/shells`.

Comment: The OP asked for a solution to run a command not enter a shell (I think another comment also noted this), you need to change or clarify the solution.